# Designing of user interface using visual workflow

Tags: visual-workflow

I am trying to design flow/user interface using visual flow designer tool. I have taken screen object from the palette and added some fields. I want to divide the flow page into multiple sections/ columns. Something like display the fields into two columns. Please check the below image which shows the four different sections

[image]

Is there any option available to modify the flow similar to UI shown in the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure a flow for two columns using a special parameter, outlined [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=vpm_url_set_layout.htm&language=en_US&release=206.5&type=0); you just add a special parameter, as in:

```
/flow/flowName?flowLayout=twoColumn
```

You can also do so in the Lightning Experience, albeit [with some limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=vpm_considerations_design_layout.htm&language=en_US&release=206.5&type=0). You can configure this when adding the flow to a Lightning App/Page/etc.

Finally, Jitendra took the time to write [a blog post](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/creating-two-column-layout-in-flow/) for how you can do this with JavaScript in Visualforce. This is an unsupported hack, so make sure you test your flows that use this design before each new release in a pre-release sandbox.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is very helpful. Now I can divide the flow layout into 2 column at runtime.
I have one more doubt. Can we create multiple tabs/ multiple windows in a flow layout?

Comment: @amitpatil That's not currently a feature. As I understand it, this may be something you can do in the future, but not today. Flows are not meant to be a complete replacement for Visualforce or Lightning, but instead just a quick, standardized wizard that needs no code. Once you need anything more complicated than a simple wizard, Flows are no longer useful.

Comment: @Denver, CO:
I have created flow using screen object with some fields. I want to add some extra new fields based on selection of already created fields.
For ex: There is one text field say "Name:XYZ" 
Based on the value of text field, it should create extra new fields in the same flow layout.

Is it possible in visual flow?

Comment: @amitpatil This is not currently possible, but it is an item on salesforce.com's backlog. Currently, you have to use a decision element and separate screens to do something like this.